# How I resolve a message about my Facebook webhook was desactived?

Tags: facebook, messenger

List Facebook Alert:

[image]

I start the tests of Facebook messenger and this problem appear, now I can't receive requests on my server.

Answer (score 0):

I found the response. When this problem appear you resolve using this code.

curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN"

You need to send the post message again to revalidate the token.

Bye